# Can we please edit [very hard], [difficult], and (easy) out of titles?

Tags: discussion, title

I'm pretty new to Puzzling, but I've looked over a few meta posts about "difficulty". We don't have *tags* for difficulty ratings, and we don't seem to need [a star/rating system](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1391/1563) IMO.

Yet people label their puzzles regardless:

- [Mysterious Murder Mystery 3 (Very Hard)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/4687/1563)
- [The SErial Killer's killer [Difficult]](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/4341/1563)
- [The Animal Party [Security to the Party 26] - an easy one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/4410/1563)
- [Spatial IQ test puzzles - Very hard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/1932/1563)

I think this has all the problems [Doorknob mentioned](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1394/1563) in his answer, with the addition of cluttering up the titles on the front page. Square brackets are particularly bad to me, since that's how [closed], [on hold], and [duplicate] show up. Having excessive brackets makes it more difficult to skim/scan.

I'd like to edit them all out (and continue to do this as I see them), but would like to hear the community's opinion first (since like I said, new here).

To be clear, I don't care if the poster says whether they believe it's hard or not if it's worked into the body. However, the *title* shouldn't have this meta information.

Comment: Whatever is decided please be careful with certain titles which are actually part of the riddle. e.g. http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4281/are-you-clever-enough-i-hope-your-brain-wont-fall-apart

Comment: @d'alar'cop See http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1438/titling-overhaul

Comment: Difficulty is subjective. It should not be in the title. Something I find hard, may be trivial to others.

Comment: I believe PPCG (codegolf) has at least one 'advanced' tag. It's quite useful in fact. There are quite different sorts of people who might want to answer questions.

Comment: @Lembik Can you be more specific? I can't find [a tag like that](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags?page=1&tab=popular) there, so I'm unsure what you mean. Regardless, that's only half relevant, since this question is about titles.

Comment: @Geobits It turns out that tag doesn't exist anymore at PPCG. My mistake.  And yes, I am not in favour of adding it to the title.  I do think that relevant tags really help though.

Answer (score 17):

Just remove them all together. As it stands, those words are just filler text, designed to gain attention but not really useful in any way.

That's my current belief; a title should describe maybe a glimpse of the riddle, but it should not add anything else superficial to it.

Comment: One of my questions is quoted above. I used the term "an easy one" because it was an easy question, not just "to gain attention". I find your accusation rude.

Comment: An easy question to WHOM? You clearly havent addressed that. Obviously it's considered easy by you, but what's to say that's considered easy for others? Have you already judging everyone on this site, and already determined other users will find it "easy"?

Comment: In my own opinion. Which I'll grant is subjective, but not  worthless. You haven't addressed the question of your rudeness.

Comment: @AE Good questions should be objective, not subjective. Or you can see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Answer (score -2):

> the title shouldn't have this meta information.

Why not? The 'hard to skim' / 'clutter' argument doesn't seem like a strong one to me. It's (potentially) useful information.

If its not in the title then where should it be? Tags would be usable.

Comment: These words are just filler text. We don't need filler text in titles, we want descriptive titles that describe the puzzle descriptively.

Comment: @thinlyveiledquestionmark, do you really find those words totally meaningless? Even if you do, since you never answer any questions on the main site anyway, how does that affect you in any way at all?

Comment: yes, they are.   Take a look at SE network questons, and tell me if you see any question titles with "Very hard", "challenging", "Very Easy" in the titles. The answer? Extremely little to none.  Adding in artificial difficulty levels is a completely dumb idea; it is subjective, and not objective, one puzzle can be easy for some, while it might pose a challenge for others. So to add a "difficulty" level is already extremely superficial.

Comment: I agree that it's subjective; that doesn't make it worthless. I don't really care if puzzling.SE titles don't entirely conform to SE norms. And you haven't answered the second part of my question: since you never answer any questions on puzzling.SE anyway, how are you disadvantaged by these titles?

Comment: If you don't care, then all I have to say is this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243705/beta-site-degrading-in-quality-per-site-meta-discussion-reveals-that-its-not-p#comment796575_243705

Comment: No - I didn't say that I didn't care about quality. Straw man argument. I said "I don't really care ***if puzzling.SE titles don't entirely conform to SE norms***". Since you have no interest in positive participation in this community, why do you come here and continually criticise it? Seems like trolling to me.

Comment: @thinlyveiledquestionmark - you clearly don't understand how SE works.  There are some (a small number) of rules that apply uniformly to all SE sites, but most policies are adaptable to individual sites.  If puzzling finds that quantifying the difficulty of a puzzle is beneficial, then it isn't against any SE standards for them to do so.  I don't personally have a horse in the game of if it is useful or not, but saying "nobody else does it so it's wrong" is flat out incorrect logic and not constructive.

Comment: @thinlyveiledquestionmark: no. Look closely at the word 'titles'. My remark was about ***titles***.