# How can I find questions based on their difficulty?

Tags: discussion, puzzle-difficulty

I had an mobile app that had hundreds of riddles. Sadly I've used up all the riddles on the app so I was at first really excited to join Puzzling.SE because I thought I could find some fun riddles.

At first I thought *I know! I'll click on the [riddle] tag but it seems like all I can find are super difficult riddles that are really long and/or involve numbers and math and crime-scene-investigation skills. I tried sorting by  "newest", "frequent", "votes", "active", or "unanswered"* but sadly none of those seemed to help find less difficult riddles. :(

I searched meta and found [Difficulty rating on questions](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1391/difficulty-rating-on-questions) wich makes it clear that questions don't have any sort of question-specific difficulty rating or tag or anything like that.

My question then would be

## **Is there any *other* way I could sort through questions to find the easier ones?**

---

should I be looking for something besides riddles? When I think of riddles I think of somthing easy-ish like [Up the hill with 3 legs and back down with 4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/27927/up-the-hill-and-back-down)

should I be looking at a different tag then riddle, like puzzle or wordplay etc.?

Comment: The problem with a difficulty-related classification is that difficulty is pretty subjective. With riddles, it's especially hard to judge the difficulty.

Comment: I do not think it is a problem. Some question would have incorrect difficulty level, so what? Better than nothing.

Comment: There is another problem: the users who would benefit from having this feature are many, but they would unlikely to read and upvote this meta question.

Answer (score 2):

"Puzzle" is not a tag here because nearly every question here is a puzzle.

"Wordplay" usually involves multiple readings of a word, moving around letters, or looking at the sounds making up a word.

I feel like your question doesn't really have a satisfactory answer. Riddles' difficulty is very subjective: things that are obvious to you could be completely opaque to me.

That being said, the [riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddle) tag is perfectly fine for finding easy riddles. Here are some decently "easy" (hopefully) riddles I found in [riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddle):

- [I have two faces, but show you one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/13041/i-have-two-faces-but-show-you-one)
- [A mirror of events](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3530/a-mirror-of-events)
- [What thing am I?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/19837/what-thing-am-i)
- [A Riddle for Puzzlers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18309/a-riddle-for-puzzlers)

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty probably depends on the tag itself.

For me, mathematical puzzles and most riddles are pretty difficult to me but for others, they may be easier than 1 + 1. So in my opinion, if I were you, I would find tags that would seem to have hard puzzles that are really thought-provoking. Popularity and the amount of answers might also help, as the puzzle is capable of misleading in some way or is just that difficult. This would attract lots of views and attempts.

Now if there are puzzles in the "Unanswered" section, they're ***that damn hard***. After lots of time sitting in the screens of the best masterminds of Puzzling.SE, it has been unsolved. Now this excludes recently published questions, which need some more time to solve.

Answer (score 0):

There is hardly an objective measure of "difficulty", so such categorizing would be extremely subjective and hence useless. One proxy you might consider is to search for puzzles where the "asked" date and the "accepted answer" data are far apart.

You may do so using the data-query at [Data.StackExchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/queries), I guess, although I have not seen such a query yet.