# Is there a way to search for "easy" puzzles

Tags: discussion, puzzle-difficulty

We have a weekly lunch-and-learn / culture building type meeting in which we always start off with a puzzle to get people engaged.

The puzzles we present are relatively simple, like the one with fox and the hen and the feed crossing the river. While looking for a source of new puzzles, I remembered this site. But the level of difficulty of most of the puzzles around here is too high for this particular forum.

Is there any chance that I might find a handful of "easy" puzzles on this site, e.g., by filtering on a particular tag? Or should I go looking elsewhere?

Comment: After posting I found this question. That was eight years ago, so maybe there's a better answer now? Otherwise feel free to close.

https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4574/how-can-i-find-questions-based-on-their-difficulty

Comment: Indeed, things haven't changed since [How can I find questions based on their difficulty?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4574/how-can-i-find-questions-based-on-their-difficulty) - we have no tags for difficulty. However, if you find puzzles of a certain type to be easy, you could filter for puzzles of that type. e.g. a person who is genius at rebuses may search for [rebus]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have criteria on what would define an "easy" puzzle (e.g. short question text, short time between question being posed and answer being accepted, more than 10 upvotes, etc.), you can use [StackExchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/revision/1822076/2214360/easy-puzzles-for-a-given-defintion-of-easy) to create a custom query to return those results.

(The above hyperlink links to a query I made with (somewhat arbitrary) criteria to try to narrow things down to what you want.  Tweaking it might help you find exactly what you're looking for.)